# Ajax undefined id PHP post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

So, i have two files index.php and edit.php

Mainly i want to send and get id variable from index.php and print echo in edit.php
for learning ajax, but i've tried every single tutorial in internet, i follow them, unfortunately i cant figure out why i get this error, by the way here's the code :

Index.php

```
<?php  
 include ('connection.php');  
 $query ="SELECT * FROM buku ORDER BY id ASC";  
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
 ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <table>  
            <thead>  
             <tr>  
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>No Buku</td>  
                <td>Nama Buku</td>   
                <td>Tahun Terbit</td> 
                <td>Action</td>                                
            </tr>  
            </thead>                    
            <?php  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
            { ?>  
                <tr>  
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['nobuku'] ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['namabuku'] ?></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['tahunterbit'] ?></td>  
                    <td><button type="buton" class="edit" id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Edit</button>
                    </td>  
                </tr>
            <?php
            };
            ?>    
        </table> 

       <div class="tampil"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
           var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
             type:"post",
             url:"edit.php",    
             data:{id:id},
             success:function(data){
               $('.tampil').load("edit.php");
             }
            });
          });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the edit.php

```
<?php  
 include ('connection.php');  
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 echo $id;
?>
```

> issue is, when i clicked the button id=edit, in my index.php always
>   sending undefined id, it means the id variable is not sending
>   correctly, but when i edit the ajax part into alert (id), it printed
>   the id variable, so the problem is i dont have idea why it cannot send
>   id variable into edit.php page.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just a side hint: I would convert the id to string, using .toString(): I know, it doesnt concretely solve your problem, just a hint.

Comment: @pbalazek
ok im gonna try it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are first loading the edit.php with ajax and sending it the id. But then, after you have loaded the ajax request you load edit.php again, this time without the id.

You already get the response in the ajax request, you only have to use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"edit.php",    
            data:{id:id},
            success:function(data){
                $('.tampil').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try and reduce the amount of copy/past into the answer and just reproduce the most relevant parts to help identify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

change edit.php to this

```
<?php  
    include ('connection.php');  
     if (isset($_POST['id'])){
       echo $_POST['id'];
   }
    ?>
```

and

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
           var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
             type:"post",
             url:"edit.php",    
             data:{id:id},
             success:function(data){
               $('.tampil').html(data);
             }
            });
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: thx u for your feedback, but this is not suitable for my case, my issue is how to pass variable "id" from index.php to edit.php using ajax